# Combine an array into 1

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my array:

```
array = [{plant: "shrub", length: "2 meters"},
    {animal: "dog", age: "5 years old"}]
```

My desired result is:

```
desiredArray = {plant: "shrub", length: "2 meters", animal: "dog", age: "5 years old" }
```

Help me combine my array with multiple length.

Comment: `Object.assing({}, ...array)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const array = [
    { plant: 'shrub', length: '2 meters' },
    { animal: 'dog', age: '5 years old' },
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, ...val }), {});

console.log(result);
```